# how to Display Dynamic content in text Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I Want to display Different value for the title of ExpansionTile, I called showindex(index) method in front of the ExpansionTile title to get Dynamic content for the  tilte,

I already assign different value for index when the user press a button, and I pass that index value in showindex(index) method

```
                    ExpansionTile(
                                    leading: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                                    title: showindex(index),
                                    subtitle: Text("amahric words"),
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        width: 340,
                                        height: 45,
                                        color: Colors.purple,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              50, 10, 0, 0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            GeezWords[index],
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
```

Here is my function to Display different Text value Depending on the index value,

```
showindex(index) {
    if (index == 1) {
      Text(amharicWords[index]);
     
    } else {
      Text(EnglishWords[index]);
    }
```

Comment: can you add the full widget ?

Comment: i want to display the value of title  from the showindex(index) method, that means values varies depending on index, value. but what is Full widget, does it help me to achieve this

Comment: Please help me i am doing School project right now and  I FACE this challenges

Answer (score 0):

```
class Expa extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpaState createState() => _ExpaState();
}

class _ExpaState extends State<Expa> {
  int index = 0;

  final amharicWords = List.generate(4, (index) => "amhari $index");

  final EnglishWords = List.generate(4, (index) => "english $index");

  showindex(index) {
    if (index == 1) {
      return Text(amharicWords[index]);
    } else {
      return Text(EnglishWords[index]);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
      title: showindex(index),
      subtitle: Text("amahric words"),
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              index = 0;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 45,
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: Text(
              EnglishWords[index],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                index = 1;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
              child: Text("Index 1"),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Is this what you what to archive?